# Quantum Circuit Optimization with Machine Learning

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, machine-learning, optimization, qaoa

I read some paper about Quantum Circuit Optimization but I am on a low level.
And have some experience in ML.

But what I don't understand is it possible that ML can help to optimize Quantum Circuits and how does that work ?

Maybe in QAOA case , what does it bring us to optimize the Circuits ?

Comment: Hi Jeff! I'd recommend you rephrase the question to reference papers you've seen / include more specificity in areas you're interested in.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.00789.pdf.    // So what I am understand is that if you have more depth in your Circuits that the results are better but in a real Quantum Hardware you have the problem with the Noise .... so must do the "Error Mitigation" ..am I right ? :/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, some works have been in this area. Here is an example: "Quantum Circuit Learning" https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00745

and also this paper, "Learning to learn with quantum neural networks via classical neural networks"  https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.05415

and also this paper, "Experimental pairwise entanglement estimation for an N-qubit system :A machine learning approach for programming quantum hardware" https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.07754